What kind of tech stack details should be shared in a software engineering career portfolio?
I'm creating my first career portfolio and I'm a little uncertain as to how much I should be sharing regarding the tech stack used in my work experiences.
For context, here's a complete rundown of nearly everything I used in my last position as a backend engineer:

Programming Language: Java
Frameworks: Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Spring Security, JUnit5
Configuration Format: YAML
Identity & Access Management: Azure AD, ForgeRock
Incident Management: OpsGenie
Databases: DynamoDB
Search & Analytics: Datadog, Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana, SonarQube
Build & Deployment Tools: Apache Maven, Docker, Terraform
Cloud Platforms: AWS
Messaging: Kafka, RabbitMQ
Collaboration & Productivity Applications: Confluence, JIRA, Office 365, Teams, Slack
Version Control: BitBucket, GitHub
Configuration Management Database: ServiceNow
Development Methodology: Agile

Should I be sharing all of this? Or is this complete overkill?
Sorry if dumb question, but I used to work in physics and this is the first time I've had to make something like this. Not quite sure where the line is between informative and verbose in this field.

No one cares about that list. What people care about is what you've actually done.

So would you suggest just avoiding sharing this altogether? Just give the standard Work Title / Company / Duration and move on?

Nope, explain what you've actually done, achieved, in few sentences.

Great, that's easy. What about when listing a tech stack on a job application? Is there a standard for what's mentioned to the employer in that section? Usually I've just wrote "Java, Spring Boot, Maven, AWS, DynamoDB".

I'd disagree that no one cares at all about languages and frameworks.  Saying that you've worked in Java with x frameworks and C# with y frameworks gives a potential employer an idea of how quickly you can come up to speed.

But you can more effectively mention it as part of the description of what you did (implemented X on a y/z/q platform). If you must enumerate,I think you can do so in a "keywords for machine scoring" section that you don't expect the humans to spend much time looking at.

There are no laws or strict guidelines, CVs vary between country and industry, but generally speaking:

Programming Language: Java

Probably the most important part. Leave it in.

Frameworks: Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Spring Security, JUnit5

Interesting. Leave it in.

Configuration Format: YAML

Completely irrelevant. I can teach you other formats in probably less than an hour.

Incident Management: OpsGenie

Only relevant if responding to incicents and working with this tool is a major part of your job. Otherwise, only leave it in if you need something to cover whitespace.

Databases: DynamoDB

Interesting, leave it in.

Identity & Access Management: Azure AD, ForgeRock


Search & Analytics: Datadog, Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana, SonarQube


Build & Deployment Tools: Apache Maven, Docker, Terraform


Cloud Platforms: AWS


Messaging: Kafka, RabbitMQ


Configuration Management Database: ServiceNow

Can be interesting, if you were more than a normal user. If you really had to do a lot to integrate with it, if you are into the details, if you could integrate another project with them, great. If they happened to be in your project and you used them... you can drop it.

Collaboration & Productivity Applications: Confluence, JIRA, Office 365, Teams, Slack

Probably the least interesting part. If you didn't do project planning, those tools are interchangable. Like an email client. I will not hire a software developer based on which email client or office suite they used.

Version Control: BitBucket, GitHub

The only relevant info here is git.

Development Methodology: Agile

Very vague. Doesn't tell me anything. Did you use a specific agile Method? Scrum, Kanban, something else?

Should I be sharing all of this? Or is this complete overkill?

Keep the interesting bits. Everything else, put it under one heading and just list it. Then it probably is two lines instead of ten.
Generally speaking the other advice is solid, explain a little what you did with those technologies that are relevant.

I disagree with some of the comments.  I, as an employer, cared about these.  When my company is using certain tools, databases, languages, test frameworks etc, then obviously I want to hire a person that has used most of them.
At the same, you need to tell them in a sentence or two what you have done at your previous employments.

I agree. As an employer, knowing what the applicant has experience in is important. Of course list the accomplishments, but what was used for them provides context.

Don't just dump a big list of skills into your portfolio without context. It's not completely clear from your question, but I'm guessing you didn't use all of those skills on a single project (e.g. I've used BitBucket and GitHub both extensively, but never both on the same project).
My engineering portfolio is broken down by project. For each project,  I list the specific skills and tools I used for that specific project, and how I used them. Some of the skills don't really need explanation ("I used Git for version control"), but for some you should absolutely elaborate (e.g. don't just say "I used DynamoDB for a database", say what you did with it and - if it was your decision - why you used it).
Context and details are helpful for giving a clearer picture of your skills and experience, and can also help to assure the person reading your portfolio that you actually used those skills and didn't just throw in a list of things you thought sounded impressive.
If all of those skills were used on one project, it might be helpful to break the project into milestones for the purposes of making the portfolio easier to follow.

It all depends on the space you have: Are there size restrictions for your resume and is space already tight? Then prioritize and list what seems the most relevant for the job you are applying to. Otherwise, list everything, but in a clearly indicated "Skills" section. Those that care then can find the information they need, those that don't care can skip that section.
Some employers use those lists as the first point of information before reading the rest of your resume, some may not use them at all.

As a hiring manager, I am most interested in your experience with the tools and technology my existing team use (which WILL be given in the job description). If you're going to make me wade through a long list of stuff we don't use in case I find the stuff we do, then it becomes less likely your application would be successful.
What I would like to see would be examples of your experience with the tools we use, a brief description of how you used them and maybe how long ago that was. Then if you have space or it feels appropriate, the rest of your list could be in an 'Other Experience' section.
"But that means I have to manually tailor this to every employer I send it to" - Yes, yes it does.
